# full background image dosnt show full height?

Tags: facebook, css, facebook-apps

Okay so i am developing an app for facebook, and i am using a textarea which can be adjusted in size. When i start the app the whole of my background image cannot be seen unless i pull down the text area.

Is there any way to make it so the full image can be seen at all times?

I will include my css for my background.

I have been looking on google but they are mostly background images with scrollbars.

```
.fbbody
{
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 2400, height: 1200});
font-family: "lucida grande" ,tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
color: #333333;
background: url(images/background.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

if anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to ensure your `body` and `html` are `100%` eg

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
```